# How do I add a new submission step in dspace, with a new html page displayed in it?

Tags: dspace

We need to display to the user, legal conditions document before actual submission of a document to the dspace repository.
The legal document is an html page.
If I understand correctly, I need to add a new step to the submission process. **Is the right way is to add a workflow step?**

We are using XMLUI with Dspace 6 on Linux.

**How to add a new first step with a new html page, to the submission process?**

Comment: I see this question was put on hold.  Your question makes sense to me and is properly tagged as "dspace".  Please indicate which version of DSpace you are running, which UI you are using (XMLUI or JSPUI), and what actions you have tried so far.

Comment: I have completed the missing information. please remove the "On Hold". Thanks!